# SQLITE Order Column in DateTime closest to furthest Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am putting DateTimes into my SQlite DB, however, I need them to be ordered from the closest to the current date to the farthest. I do not get a DateTime datatype option for my SQlite column. So how can I order them? I cannot find anything online, and nothing i tried has worked so far.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Nothing i have tried as worked so far, so i do not have anything to share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that SQLite does not have a native datetime data type, however [it can store such data](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

All of these options will sort as you'd expect. Pick the type that fits your use case best.

Tables in SQLite (and other relational databases) are ordered however the database engine finds most convenient. You can impose an order on the results when you query, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Comment: This looks helpful so far. One least question, is there any way I can order the dates so the closest date is always at the top of the table?

Comment: The underlying order of tables in relational databases is whatever the engine decides it should be. You can order rows when you query the table, e.g. `SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY created_at DESC`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This should be enough to help.